# Adding Image Overlays on Images Using A Single Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a rather tricky situation. In short, I need to find a way to add an image overlay, onto an image, using only a single image tag. More specifically I am trying to add a resize icon to the bottom right of an image alerting the user that they can resize the image by cliking and dragging at the markers position.

I am using inline CKEditor, with Interact.js to allow images to be resized inline. All works fine, but without this image marker it isn't very obvious that you can resize the image.

Unfortunately :before and :after on img tags does not work. If I could just do that, it would be fine. I can not wrap the image in a container because that disrupts the image editing features like dragging and dropping into another position. The entire effect must be contained within the img tag.

The best I have been able to come up with is adding a css border image of the resize icon and collapsing the left and top borders. It adds the marker in a way which will work, but I would prefer the marker to be on the image, and not positioned outside of it like in my preview. Also, because it is a border image I can't add a custom cursor to let the user know that they can click there.

So any ideas? I might have to just settle for this and move on. I would prefer a pure CSS solution to this, but I am not opposed to using javascript and/or jquery to achieve it. I tried doing something where when you moused over it the image would get a wrapper with an image that I positioned, but it doesn't work as one would expect.

[image]

```
#foo{ padding:0 16px 16px 0}
#foo:hover{
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-border-image: url(/templates/client/js/ckeditor/plugins/compuimage/images/resize.png) 50 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(/templates/client/js/ckeditor/plugins/compuimage/images/resize.png) 50 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(/templates/client/js/ckeditor/plugins/compuimage/images/resize.png) 50 round;     
    border-width:0 16px 16px 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add you code also with post.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what code I would add as this is more of an ambiguous question. If you wanted to see the code that I am using for the css image borders, I will add it to my post. But, I don't know what use posting my code for the ckeditor and image resizer itself would accomplish.

Comment: Sort of, but this solution has problems. There are a lot of issues that come with having to manage a separate element to track the image resizer, such as how this all works in IE, how the image reacts to being dragged and dropped into another location, how the image handles haivng an element overlap it's resizeable areas, among others. This is really the reason why I am trying to avoid using a wrapper element to achieve this.

Comment: Sure, I get that. (Here is a better working version of the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8eLbt16L/3/) I don't see a purely CSS method of doing this (which is really hacking an `:after` method, which at least I couldn't find a way to do that). You could of course remove the resizer wrapper `ondragstart`, so I don't see that being a huge deal. (I don't follow the resizable areas bit.) Short of *replacing* the `img` tag with a tag that accepts pseudo-elements (which would seem more complicated), I think a simple `span` wrapper and CSS backfill is the most straight-forward method available.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You might be right, maybe it will be possible to use a wrapper element around the image. I had some vague success with doing that, but when it came to moving the image around I couldn't figure a way to get around some of the issues it presented. I will see what I can do though. Also, I need to set pointer-events to none so that I can still click the image underneath it, but then I can't add a pretty custom cursor letting the user know they can drag, but that's not a big deal at all.

Comment: Another option of course would be to use Javascript to detect the position offset of the element on the page and absolute-position your resizer icon on the computed bottom-right corner. This is probably also messy (when dragging and actual resizing, for instance), but I suppose it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how valid this is, nor if it works consistently cross browser, but I managed to nest an image in an image...

```
<img src="http://www.koala.net/images/stories/animals/birds/flightless/emu.jpg" >
<span><img src="http://www.greatsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Reshape-Image-Resize.gif" /></span>
</img>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v2j20L7x/

Works in Chrome. Hopefully works elsewhere and does what you are after.

Good luck!

Comment: Very interesting idea! I never actually thought to open and close the image like that. I tested in my versions of chrome, ie and ff and it worked in all of them. I'm not sure it would work in older browsers, but for what I am after this might be fine. I will give it some more investigating, but this might actually work well. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah so I just tried this, and it doesn't seem to work actually. For one I would need to use percentages with the absolute positioned icon, percentages that relate to the img not the document, which isn't possible. Looking at the element in inspector I see that the inner element of the img is no longer part of the element itself. Also, CKEditor doesn't allow this kind of content inside the image and will remove it naturally.

Comment: Using a full tag syntax like `<img></img>` is valid in XHTML but not in HTML4/5. What I would worry about with this is an implicit quirks mode issue, although I suspect HTML5 might handle it anyways (because it's much looser than HTML4 in interpretation logic).